# Server 2012 windows update stuck forever

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-update, svchost

I have a problem with Windows Server 2012 (NON R2).
Basically, svchost/wuauserv is stuck using 100% of 1 core (and 2GB RAM), indefinitely.

I tried pretty much everything I found online:

- Made sure there is enough diskspace (8GB now)
- Used Reset tools like ResetWUEng.cmd and Reset-WindowsUpdate.ps1
- Did a:

  - "dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth"
  - sfc /scannow
  - cd C:\Windows\System32\wbem\AutoRecover -> for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mof *.mfl') do mofcomp %s"
- Used WindowsUpdateDiagnostic.diagcab
- Tried WSUS offline (also hangs)
- Set windows update to never update
- Restarting VM, Restarting windows update service
- Left it overnight
- Manually installed latest monthly rollup (Februari 2019). This installed, but windows update still uses 25% (1 core) CPU indefinitely

I searched everywhere and I don't know what to do except for reinstall windows. At this point I just want to know what the problem is.

In the log file, lots of:

```
DtaStor WARNING: Attempted to add URL http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2019/01/windows8-rt-kb4480094-x64_760d29d4007187bd160761d09c6b6600a5a84249.msu for file dg0p1ABxh70WB2HQnGtmAKWoQkk= when file has not been previously added to the datastore
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you got a monitoring software ? like nable or nagios, some of those software use the windows update service to list if the server is missing or not update. Had in the past a bug like that, I removed and re-isntalled the monitoring software and the bug went away

Comment: No, and windows update used to work before.

Comment: Ok, but if the service is disable or close, wuauserv restart and use the %CPU ? I just want to be sure, as something call the process to open if so (if not a monitoring software, a gpo?), or the bug just happen when you look for update ?

Comment: After restart of wuauserv the CPU usage is normal, until it starts searching for updates again.

Comment: Anyone? Left it over the weekend, still 25% cpu on svchost....

Answer (score 6):

For anyone reading this: I finally solved the problem.
After searching hundreds of topics I found someone who said disabling "desktop experience" solved his problems.
I didn't understand why this would be related but I tried it anyway and lo and behold - it found 3 updates after 5min of searching.
After restart, it now says "Your PC is up to date" - also after around only 5mins.

I have no idea why this solved it - we have some other server 2012 machines that have it enabled without problems.

Comment: Thank you ITWP. After one week with the CPU 50% and tried a lot of possible solutions, scripts and patches, your comment  "disabling desktop experience" solved this problem in Windows Server 2012

Comment: Finally something that works - don't know why nor care,  just nice to get the server updated.  Found a simple description of how to remove the Desktop Experience: https://support.symantec.com/us/en/article.tech228671.html